# Manual signings of the transactions are not visibles during checking(fabric 1.4)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are supposed to be able to sign a transaction with multiple identities, and that can be a requirement configured in the policies.

But I'm failing to make this working, that is, I have a policy requiring multi signatures, so I sign the transaction file(.tx) successively with the MSP information of the two organizations, but when I submit the transaction then,
the orderer or the peers will reject it, saying that "**Signature set did not satisfy policy ...**".

And what is weird is that this check ignores the others signatures I did, it will just consider the signature done automatically by the command submitting the transaction: **peer channel update** or **peer chaincode instantiate**, as if
this last signature invalidated the signatures that I applied before manually.

Some idea about what I'm missing?

The commands that I used:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-signconfigtx
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-signpackage

The variables that I modified to make a different signature:

- **CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID**
- **CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH**

-- edited

I'm working with the **first-network** example of Fabric version 1.4.0:

- [crypto-config.yaml](http://snippi.com/s/8lwtf9q)
- [config.tx](http://snippi.com/s/5vmfnxu)

This is **Application** section in the configtx.yaml file where I updated the **Writers** policy from **ANY Writers** to **MAJORITY Admins**:

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
# the application side of the network
Organizations:

# Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
# For Application policies, their canonical path is
#   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

In the cli container, I can create the channel without any problem:

```bash
peer channel create --channelID $CHANNEL_ID --orderer orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --file channel-artifacts/channel.tx
```

And after I join the peers peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com without any problem.

The issues start when I try to submit the anchor peers creation transactions:

```bash
peer channel update --channelID $CHANNEL_ID --orderer orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --file  channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx
```

I have the error message:

> Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit
>    threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

More exhaustive logs are provided by the orderer: http://snippi.com/s/hlxkvl3

The logs show that the orderer tried these actions to validate the signatures of the transaction:

1. Line 2: trying to evaluate the policy **/Channel/Writers**
2. Line 4: trying to evaluate the policy **/Channel/Application/Writers**
3. Line 6: trying to evaluate the policy **/Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins**
4. Line 20: **signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins**
5. Line 22: trying to evaluate the policy **/Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Admins**
6. Line 29: **Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Admins**
7. Line 31: Evaluation Failed: Only 1 policies were satisfied, but needed 2 of [ Org1MSP.Admins Org2MSP.Admins ]
8. Line 34: Evaluating the Policy **/Channel/Orderer/Writers**
9. Line 43: **Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers**
10. Line 48: **Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Application.Writers Orderer.Writers ]**

When I saw this error, I said OK, I will first sign the transaction with Org1's admin, and then submit it with Org2's admin signature:

```bash
peer channel signconfigtx -f channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx

CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051

peer channel update --channelID $CHANNEL_ID --orderer orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --file  channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx
```

I got the error message:

> Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit
>   threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

The logs from the orderer: http://snippi.com/s/qjb7dlv

The logs show this time that the orderer first fails to find the signature of Org1's admin(line 28 for example), then finds the signature for Org2's admin(line 45). And neither of the two policies **/Channel/Application/Writers** and **/Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers** were met (line 64).

I can see that the size of the transaction file increases when I sign it, as proof as the file is well altered. But why this signature that is expected for example by the orderer during the control seems to be not visible to it?

Just to move forward, as temporary workaround I used the orderer's admin MSP to submit the transactions of the anchor peers:

```bash
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin\@example.com/msp/

peer channel update --channelID $CHANNEL_ID --orderer orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --file  channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx
```

This time the command worked. But strangely, it worked only because I signed previously the transaction with Org1's admin MSP, that is, if I try to submit the transaction with the orderer's admin MSP without sign it before with Org1's admin MSP, it fails. Strange again, if I start by signing the transaction with the orderer's admin and then by submitting it with the Org1's admin, the command fails again.

I have about the same issues when I try to instantiate the chaincode as we can see in the logs of the orderer: http://snippi.com/s/324asxa

It would be nice to have an in-depth guide on how Fabric's signature mechanism works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Readers and Writers policies must be able to be satisfied by a single signature, as the transaction format allows exactly one signature.

The Admins policy is the default policy used to govern mutation of the channel config (such as modifying the Readers or Writers policies).  Mutation of channel config does support the multi-signature workflow via `peer channel signconfigtx`.

---

> We are supposed to be able to sign a transaction with multiple identities, and that can be a requirement configured in the policies.

Some transactions, like configuration update transactions may be signed with multiple identities.  Other transactions, like chaincode invocations (including invocations of lscc like `peer chaincode instantiate`) can generally only have one signer.

> But I'm failing to make this working, that is, I have a policy requiring multi signatures, so I sign the transaction file(.tx) successively with the MSP information of the two organizations, but when I submit the transaction then, the orderer or the peers will reject it, saying that "Signature set did not satisfy policy ...".

If this is a configuration update, then pasting more of the log would be helpful.  Most often, if the `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` and `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` variables are set correctly, then policies are not satisfied because the identity does not satisfy the required rule (usually 'admin').

If this is a normal chaincode invocation, like a lifecycle operation, then the network is misconfigured, as these invocations must be able to be satisfied via a single submitter signature.

> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-signconfigtx

This command is indeed intended to allow you to gather multiple signatures for a config update.

> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-signpackage

This command is not particularly useful, and is probably a bit misleading.  It adds signatures so that an administrator can manually verify agreement, but these signatures are not used when evaluating any Fabric policies.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. I added more details to the problem description.

Comment: If the chaincode invocation must be able to satisfied via a single submitter signature, then that explains my problem, because the **Writers** policy of the **Application** in my **configtx.yaml** is configured as **"MAJORITY Admins"**.

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out explicitly that the Readers and Writers policies must be satisfiable by a single signature.